# hook_preprocess_page(): how to tell a views page?

Tags: views, 7, theming, javascript

Im writing a custom module that need to insert some javascript and css files only in a Views page.

Im using hook_preprocess_page, but I can not tell if the current page is from a view:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&vars)
{
    var_dump($vars); //output: nothings that reference the views!
    if([view page])
    {
        drupal_add_js([...]);
        drupal_add_css([...]);
        // Rebuild scripts 
        $scripts = drupal_get_js();
        $vars['scripts'] = $scripts;
        // Same for css
    }
}
```

I know i could use a template file (page-my_view_page_path.tpl.php), but the js and extra css must be included only if my module is enabled; **so I like to keep this things directly inside my module code**.

Ideas?

Comment: You can use template files in your module.

Comment: @Jeremy: add your answer explaining how, so people can vote and argue.

Comment: It wasn't directly related to the answer, just pointing out that a tpl file can be included in a module. a DANieL seemed to be indicating that it couldn't.

Comment: well.. i *could* include the theme page.tpl, but my goal is to keep this module totally indipendent from the theme..

Comment: You can implement Views' templates pre-processing your module, as suggested in Jeremy French's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`views_get_page_view()`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_get_page_view) finds out what, if any, page view is currently in use. If it returns NULL, then the current page is not a views' page.

But using `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_css()` in a `hook_preprocess_page()` won't work as expected because the variable `$script` and `$style` variables have already been set by [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6). Views's template preprocessing (see Jeremy French's answer) is probably a better place to add your CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I updated my answer for you second paragraph -  i know is a good practice to add css or js in the theme (theme_preprocess_*), but my need is module dependandt.

Comment: Excellent, views_get_page_view just gets the already loaded view from cache, so it shouldn't have a performance impact. IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Strae My suggestion was to use `HOOK_preprocess_views_view(&$variables)` or another Views' template preprocess hook instead of `HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables)`. This way you can get the views in `$variables` and use `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_css()` safely.

Answer (score 11):

There is a lengthy thread on [preprocessors for views](http://drupal.org/node/303586) here. [This comment](http://drupal.org/node/303586#comment-2552974) looks very simple to me.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  //dpm($theme_registry);
  $theme_registry['views_view__YOUR_VIEW_NAME_HERE']['preprocess functions'][] = 'mymodule_preprocess_func';
}

// now go on and play with your new preprocess function
function mymodule_preprocess_func(&$vars) {
  // etc
}
```

Comment: I agree that preprocessing the output of the View instead of the entire page is probably the more correct approach.

Answer (score 8):

If you're in a hook_preprocess_page() then, by definition, your view has a page display and a menu path, which must be unique - so you can do this:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&vars)
{
    var_dump($vars); //output: nothings that reference the views!
    if($_GET['q'] == 'my/view/path')
    {
        drupal_add_js([...]);
        drupal_add_css([...]);
    }
}
```

If you have arguments being passed to this page, so you need parts of `$_GET['q']`, then do this instead with Drupal's `arg()` function:

```
if(arg(0) == 'my' && arg(1) == 'view' && arg(2) == 'path')
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg

Comment: I would not recommend examining $_GET['q']. Use [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/6) or [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) instead. Neither requires an argument if you are inspecting the current page, and they both cache their results.

Comment: Using drupal_add_js() and drupal_add_css() in a hook_preprocess_page() won't work as expected because the variable $script and $style variables have already been set by template_preprocess_page(). User views_get_page_view() to retrieve the view for the current page (if any).

Answer (score 3):

For me this one works:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $view = (array)views_get_page_view();
  if (!empty($view)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding JS or CSS to a specific callback then better to use [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7):