# Variable to check if the page is of some other Content Type

Tags: 7, nodes

The variables `$page` and `$teaser` are very helpful but is there a way to check if I'm in a different kind of Content Type? For example, if I made a content type named **Products**, what can I type in my template file `page.tpl.php` which will display HTML only if the page being viewed is of type **Products**?

Comment: Quick note, `$page` and `$teaser` are view mode flags, not content types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place this in your theme's template.php, replacing 'THEMENAME' with the name of your theme:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['some_html'] = '';
  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'product') {
    $variables['some_html'] = '<p>Hello world!</p>';
  }
}
```

And use this in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $some_html; ?>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the HTML string in your template file, I would do this in template.php:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['print_extra_header'] = false;
  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'product') {
    $variables['print_extra_header'] = true;
  }
}
```

And use this in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($print_extra_header) : ?> <h1>THIS GETS PRINTED</h1> <?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure to clear the cache after creating the THEMENAME_preprocess_page function, otherwise Drupal will not know it's there and it will not run.

Comment: Is there an alternate method where the markup will be placed in `page.tpl.php` instead of in `template.php`? I'm looking for something more like: `<?php if(condition) : ?> <h1>THIS GETS PRINTED</h1> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: You could do `<?php if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'product') : ?><h1>THIS GETS PRINTED</h1><?php endif; ?>`, but that is not recommended. Drupal uses preprocess functions so you can keep the logic out of your tpl.php files. Otherwise, tpl.php files can get messy very quickly. I added an alternative method to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks marcvangend!I'm going to try and learn Views templates next. Any good suggestions on that one?

Comment: How about to check if it's a Views page? How do you do that?

Comment: For theming Views output, see [Views theming basics](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/views-theming-basics). For checking if the page is a view in THEMENAME_preprocess_page, see [hook_preprocess_page(): how to tell a views page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231) (I like the views_get_page_view() method best).

Comment: The function just gets a parameter; the variable `$hook` is not passed to `THEMENAME_preprocess_page()`, in the same way it is not passed to [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

Comment: I tried the alternative version but I get a blank page when clearing the cache. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264550/can-i-target-a-specific-node-type-in-page-tpl-php