# Can I target a specific node type in page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I just created a template `page--article.tpl.php` to apply ton nodes of the `[article] type`. It works when declared in the `template.php` file.
My problem is that there is a very slight change compared to the generic `page.tpl.php`, nothing worth having another file.

I was wondering if I could place the adde part between a condition, just as I could do with `if $is_front`
Something like:

```
<?php if ($node->type == 'article')
  // render my thingees
?>
```

I would be glad if someone could tell me.

--- Edit, to answer Kiwimind ---

I did the test with the 'page' content type, so I didn't have to skip my `page--article.tpl.php` file. I checked that 'page' was the actual machine name and 'nature' is my theme's actual name, it works on other functions.
I wrote in `template.php`

```
/**
 * Détection du type de contenu pour affecter le template page
 * https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264550/can-i-target-a-specific-node-type-in-page-tpl-php
 */

function nature_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['is_page'] = false;
  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'page') {
    $variables['is_page'] = true;
  }
}
```

Then in `page.tpl.php`

```
<?php if ($is_page) : ?> 
    <h1>This is a “page” content</h1> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Nothing more, nothing less. Do you see any missing (or unnecessary) character, that could trigger a parse error? For I still get a whole blank page when clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3):

As shown on [Variable to check if the page is of some other Content Type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4856/variable-to-check-if-the-page-is-of-some-other-content-type), you can drop into template.php something like the following:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['print_extra_header'] = false;
  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'product') {
    $variables['print_extra_header'] = true;
  }
}
```

then in your template, add in

```
<?php if ($print_extra_header) : ?> <h1>THIS GETS PRINTED</h1> <?php endif; ?>
```

So effectively you're checking on the node type in a preprocess page, to pass a custom variable to the template for you to act on.

Comment: I tried and I got a blank page when clearing the cache. I'll carry on with a page--article.tpl.php, nevermind. Thank you anyway, It could have been just the right thing I needed.

Comment: If you paste in the code that you tried, I'm quite happy to have a look. There are a few things in the above example that would need amending for your use case.

Comment: I understood what went wrong. I was already using the function `XXX_preprocess_page()` to target the specific template I was talking about in the very beginning. I copied your code underneath and then had two functions with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variable as per your condition on your module file and get this variable from your .tpl file after that set your condition.