# Check if viewing a Views page

Tags: views

How do I check if the page I'm viewing is a Views page? I want the breadcrumbs to be hidden if the user is viewing the view page I made, which I named "Products."

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 7.x-3.0-beta3.

Comment: I am sorry, you didn't mention the drupal and views version.

Comment: Similar but not quite duplicate http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231/hook-preprocess-page-how-to-tell-a-views-page/235#235

Answer (score 7):

Following [Jeremy French](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/182/jeremy-french) reply, I must say that you can do it like this :

```
if(function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view()){...YOUR CODE HERE...}
```

Taken [from here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231/hook-preprocess-page-how-to-tell-a-views-page/235#242):

> views_get_page_view() finds out what, if any, page view is currently
>   in use. If it returns NULL, then the current page is not a views'
>   page.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty would be to use CSS - take the class Drupal assigns to the views page and then do something like:

```
.drupal-views-page-class .breadcrumb-container {display:none}
```

Of course, you need to use your actual class names.

Comment: Hehe, you're right. Quick and dirty. I'll consider this if all else fails. Thanks @Mike this one made me laugh. :-)

Comment: Very, very dirty.

Answer (score 2):

For d6 site the following trick might work.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_render()
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_render($view) {
  if ($view->name === 'my_products_view') {
    drupal_set_breadcrumb();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a method which uses the standard way of checking through `<?php if(condition) : ?> This gets printed <?php endif; ?>`? That way I can just check if it's a Views page and *not* print the breadcrumbs.

Comment: @enchance - Depends on where exactly you want to check this. Maybe `<?php if(isset($view->name)) : ?>This gets printed<?php endif; ?>` works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that shouldn't be displayed on certain content types. There's an easy approach for this:

```
<?php if (!empty($node) && (($node->type != 'article') && ($node->type != 'webform'))): ?>
     This content is shown everywhere except on articles and webforms. Yet it doesn't show up on views pages either while it should.
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it occured to me that it would hide this content for views pages as well (because the node is empty there: `(!empty($node)`).

My workaround for this is:

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view()){
      $viewspage = "yes";
    }
  ?>
<?php if (((!empty($node)) || (!empty($viewspage))) && (($node->type != 'article') && ($node->type != 'webform'))): ?>
     This content is shown everywhere except on articles and webforms. It does show up on the other content types ànd the views pages. So it's ok.
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is working, but I wondered if this is the right approach. It looks a bit like a kindergarten-method.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works in `hook_preprocess_page()` and in `hook_preprocess_html()` as well:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $view = (array)views_get_page_view();
  if (!empty($view)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```