# How to translate the description metatag for a view

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, meta-tags

I have a multilingual site based on drupal 7 with Internationalization i18n and Metatags modules.
I made a multilingual view and it works fine, I could translate all entities except the view-description (and of course the metatag description).
I would like to have for each language a different meta tag description of the view.

As I can read in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1986032), it seems there is still no solution.

Is there any workaround? 
Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

You could add something in the html.tpl.php along these lines:

```
  <?php
  if((function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view()) && ($language->language == 'fr')){ ?>
      ...Your metatag here...
  <?php  
  }elseif((function_exists('views_get_page_view') && views_get_page_view()) && ($language->language == 'de')){ ?>
      ...Your metatag here...  
  <?php } ?>
```

> views_get_page_view() finds out what, if any, page view is currently
>   in use. If it returns NULL, then the current page is not a views'
>   page.

[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231/hook-preprocess-page-how-to-tell-a-views-page/235#242)

This line of code may come in handy as well, to figure out which view:

```
$view = views_get_page_view();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741890/get-current-page-view-in-drupal#17360255)

Is this enough to help you on the way?

Comment: It could be a solution,but I would prefer not to edit the tpl files.
Moreover adding the meta tags in this way, would duplicate the meta tags that are already set by the module (I think I should disable the submodule Metatag-Views, in order to avoid duplicates).
Anyway I'll try your code. Thanks.